# need help understanding the cause of the run-time error and how to fix it

Tags: java, runtime, runtime-error

the code's purpose is to find the binomial coefficient (n,k)
I'm receiving a runtime error

```
import java.util.*;

public class pract5ex11 {
public static long combinRec (int n, int k){
    long answer;
    if (k==0 || n==k) {
            answer = 1;
        }
    else {

        answer = combinRec(n-1,k)+combinRec(n-1,k-1);

    }
    return answer;
}

public static void main (String []args){
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter first number");
    int n = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter second number, must be equal or greater");
    int k = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println(combinRec(n,k));

}
}
```

Also i am confused in certain points:_
the static and non-static significance in java
the command center line
the keyword "this" in java
if there are certain websites or references to understand through them these points I'd be grateful,
thank you

Comment: "*I'm receiving a runtime error*" => What error? Can you post the stack trace, which contains useful information, such as the line on which the error occurred.

Comment: [The Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) contains a "Learning the Java Language" section.

Answer (score 1):

You have it reversed: `k` should be smaller/equal, otherwise you will have a chain of calls for which

```
if (k == 0 || n == k) {
```

is never entered resulting in a `StackOverflowError`, since you are recurring with the call `combinRec(n - 1, k)`, and that doesn't change `k`. So, if `n < k` and `k != 0`, then `k == 0 || n == k` will never be true. *But*, if `k < n`, it would eventually be true since repeatedly subtracting `1` from `n` would eventually make `n` and `k` equal.

Comment: @ arshajii thank you, it is weird though that in the question it was specifically stated "Make sure that n is less than k"